# Angular NullInjectorError: No Provider for MatDialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

so when I try to load my angular app, i get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): 
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> MatDialog]:    
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> MatDialog]:
```

my ts file looks like this, every other help question said to add MatDialog to my NgModule imports, but I have done that and am still receiving the error. Most of those errors were StaticInjectorErrors and mine is a NullInjectorError but I am not sure what the difference is between those two.

```js
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig, MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { compileNgModule } from '@angular/compiler';
import { AppDialog } from '../appDialog/app-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
@NgModule({
  imports: [MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MatDialogConfig, MatDialogModule]
})
export class AppComponent {


  constructor(private appService: AppService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  openDialog() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.height = "350px";
    dialogConfig.width = "600px";
    dialogConfig.data = {
    };

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AppDialog, dialogConfig);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('closed dialog');
      this.success = result;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I also added MatDialog to my providers array:
providers: [{
    provide: MatDialog
  }]

and that didn't change anything

Comment: Did you tried to define those imports on you `app.module.ts` file instead of `app.component.ts`?

Comment: instead of, or in addition to?

Comment: Instead of doing the import on the component as stated by the answer below

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please note that in `Angular Material` you have to import all elements `module` into your `module.ts`. You have to import and add module in your `module.ts` like this

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';


import : [MatDialogModule]
```

For reference see the example from official documentation [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rknvmmmgbba)

Comment: so i have to import it twice?

Comment: No, you don't have to import `MatDialogModule` in `module.ts` only not in `component.ts`.
Just import `MatDialog` in your `component.ts`. Please see the reference example that i referred in my answer

Answer (score 38):

In my situation, I was seeing this error while trying to build a dialog component like:

`my-dialog.component.ts`

```
<mat-dialog-container>
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>I am a dialog</p>
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button>Click me</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</mat-dialog-container>
```

The problem was that I was using `mat-dialog-container`.  This is not required for components that you'll be rendering via `matDialog.open(MyDialogComponent)`

Instead, just remove `mat-dialog-container` entirely and just use the child nodes.